# Image size in different iOS cameras?

Tags: ios, camera

I am creating a feature in my app that lets people take photo in the device camera, and add an overlay above the taken image.

I am doing so by merging the image received from the camera with an other overlay image.

I know that on the iPhone 4, the camera image is 1936 x 2592. So I prepared an overlay image in the same size.

I wonder if the image size is different on other devices like iPad, iPhone 5 or in the front camera of those devices? Since i have only iPhone 4 I can not check that.

BTW if anyone knows a better way to approach that I will appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the image size will depend on the camera available. iPhone 4 has a 5.0 megapixel camera that produces 2592x1936 pixels. The iPhone 4S for example sports an 8 megapixel camera with pictures of 3264×2448 pixels. Older phones have lower resolution cameras and the iPad 2 seems to have a 0.7 megapixel camera...

In short you cannot really rely on a specific image size especially if you want to be future-proof. Either you have to supply the overlays in all specific resolutions and update appropriately, or have a rather large version that will be scaled down (might not be pretty). The best way though would to render the overlay live on the phone if possible (you'd need to have a vector representation for that).

Comment: Can i try to use SVG for that?

Comment: Sure that would be a good and portable way to bring the graphics into your app. All you need now is a method to draw those graphics onto the image. I don't know about specific libraries for this but it looks like https://github.com/mattrajca/SVGKit and https://github.com/splashdust/SVGQuartzRenderer seem to be a good start.

Comment: It'd be a huge amount less work to use a PDF asset for that. Rendering of PDFs is built in to the OS.

Answer (score 4):

I did a little testing and here are the results I have so far, feel free to add to my list.

iPhone6

```
Front:
960.0 - 3x
1280.0 - 4x
Back:
2448.0 - 3x
3264.0 - 4x
```

iPhone4

```
Front:
480.0 - 3x
640.0 - 4x
Back:
1936.0 - 121x
2592.0 - 162x
```

iPad4

```
Front:
960.0 - 3x
1280.0 - 4x
Back:
1936.0 - 121x
2592.0 - 162x
```